# Get amount of time to run function in C

Tags: c, time

So this is pretty basic, but I don't really know C.

I want to find the number of milliseconds something takes to run, not clock (CPU) cycles.

I tried using

```
struct timeval start,end;
double dif;

gettimeofday(&start, 0);
//do stuff
gettimeofday(&end, 0);
dif = (end - start) / 1000.0;
printf("The time taken was %lf \n",dif);
```

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to compile:

> bubble.c: In function ‘main’:
>  bubble.c:55: error: invalid
>   operands to binary - (have ‘struct timeval’ and ‘struct timeval’)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
dif = (end - start) * 1000;
```

to

```
dif = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000 
+ (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / 1000;
```

In pseudocode:

```
Get the seconds part of the time delta
Multiply by 1000 to get milliseconds
Get the microseconds part of the time delta
Divide that part by 1000
Add that part to the milliseconds from seconds delta
```

Comment: This should work OK under most circumstances.  But I'd advise using timersub() with "struct time_val" instead.

Comment: @moshbear - you changed the post on me :)  Your current version is *much* less fragile :)

Comment: Methinks I just implemented `timersub()`, but without a proper normalization.

Comment: @paulsm4: I changed the code because I forgot to factor in the fact that the usec delta may be negative, in which case the sec delta needs incrementing. I also fixed an operator typo and added pseudocode.

Comment: Great, new one is awesome.  Just switched the `1000`s to `1000.0` as to make it a double.  Thanks.

Comment: It was wonderful :).  Made it very clear as to what you were doing.  Wish every answer on SO was this detailed.

Comment: Well, I for one don't understand the special handling of the -ve microseconds. That term will be picked by automatically by the corresponding increment in tv_sec. The code given double counts.

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
dif = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / 1000.0;
```

Note 1: You need the tv_sec to handle even a short duration crossing a second ticking over.

Note 2: Second term divides by a 1000.0 so as to use floating point rather than integer division.

Comment: absolutely correct.  That's why I recommended timersub() with moshbear's original post.  Before he edited it, he recommended "dif = (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / 1000;", which would NOT have worked under all circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

For quick benchmark, I'd use `clock()` and `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`.

Here's some macro code I use:

```
#define CLOCK_TICK(acc, ctr)  ctr = std::clock()
#define CLOCK_TOCK(acc, ctr)  acc += (std::clock() - ctr)
#define CLOCK_RESET(acc) acc = 0
#define CLOCK_REPORT(acc) (1000. * double(acc) / double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC))

static clock_t t1a, t1c;


int main()
{
   while (true)
   {
     CLOCK_RESET(t1a);
     init_stuff();
     CLOCK_TICK(t1a, t1c);
     critical_function();
     CLOCK_TOCK(t1a, t1c);

     std::cout << "This round took " << CLOCK_REPORT(t1a) << "ms.\n";
   }
}
```

You can get a higher-resolution clock out of the new `<chrono>` header. The macros should be straight-forward to adapt.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you're including the correct header ("#include ")
2. Use "timersub()" to get the difference, instead of subtracting end-start:

http://linux.die.net/man/3/timeradd

'Hope that helps .. PSM

Answer (score 0):

On Linux the best way to achieve this is to use the times(2) interface rather than gettimeofday(2) have a read of the man page.

> man 2 times.

It has exquisite fidelity.